# Error in trying to run Python code online

Tags: python, python-2.7, powershell

I was trying to make a simple Python game for some struggling math students at my high school, however our computers are not allowed to run Python due to security issues.  So I decided to give them the code and have them run it online, but every site I go to says that the code has an EOFerror and an indention error. I have ran the code a dozen times in Powershell and everything was fine. It is always focused on my `raw_input()` statements. Can someone please tell me what is going on and any solution would by greatly appreciated. This is just the Intro so there is no math, just something to set the story.

```
def cell():
      print """
      "Welcome roomie!"
      You wake up to find yourself in a jail cell
      "You have been sleeping since the guards threw you in here.
      They must have hit you pretty hard, ha ha ha."
      You look around
      finally your eyes focus on the source of the voice
      across the room was a man
      he looked as if he was nothing but skin and bone.
      Then you noticed the scar... it ran down his arm
      It was an open wound,
      but wasn't bleeding just black.
      The man followed your eyes
      "Ah so you noticed, yes I am forsaken."
      1) Remain quit
      2) Ask about the forsaken
      3) Quickly check your body for scars
      4) Scream
      Please choose one:"""

      answer = raw_input("> ")

      if answer == "1":
          print '"You don\'t talk much"'
          cell_name()
      elif answer == "2": 
          print '"Not sure, all I know is if you have a scar like this"'
          print '"They throw you in jail."'
          cell_name()
      elif answer == "3":
          print '"Don\'t worry I already checked you."'
          cell_name()
      elif answer == "4":
          print '"Shut up! Jeez pansy."'
          cell_name()
      else:
          print "Pick one of the numbers"
          cell()

def cell_name():
        print "Well whats your name kid."

        name = raw_input("> ")

        print "Alright, nice to meet ya %r" % name
        print "Well my name is Esman."
        destroyed_cell()

def destroyed_cell():
        print """
        All of a sudden you hear a rumble...
        rumble...
        rumble...
        silence.
        "What do you suppose that wa..."
        Crash!
        Huge parts of the ceiling had fallen down
        one had nearly crushed you
        instead it had landed perfectly right next to you
        the force was enough to break through the floor
        you turn to check on Esman
        But a huge piece of the ceiling had landed on him
        1) Stare in bewilderment
        2) try and help him
        3) he's a dead man, leave him
        Please choose one:"""

        answer = raw_input("> ")

        if answer == "1":
            print "Hurry kid get out of here."
        elif answer == "2":
            print "It's no use you have to save yourself"
        elif answer == "3":
            print "Run!"
        else:
            print "Pick one of the numbers" 

cell()
```

Comment: Please give us an example of a site that's giving you errors with this.

Comment: You probably need an extra empty line at the end of your code. And replace 8 space indentation with 4 spaces

Comment: Tried it on [compileonline](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_python_online.php). The `EOFError: EOF when reading a line` error is caused by `answer = raw_input("> ")` However, it works on [repl.it](http://repl.it/Rgh)

Comment: Did you try on an interactive website? If not, maybe you forgot to fill the "input" box?

Comment: Also, I don't know what country you come from, but it's certainly inappropriate for a teacher to be using slurs like "pansy" to their students.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code at http://repl.it/languages/Python and it works